# calling methods at runtime

Tags: .net

What is used to call methods at runtime?

Can either one work a> Delegate b> Reflection API

Comment: Please clarify your question. Also, if it's homework, then please say so.

Comment: I think, you always call a method at runtime :)

Answer (score 1):

If you only have the method name (as a string) and an object of the type that implements the method, then, yes you need Reflection.  If you have a delegate, then you can invoke it directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegates and reflections to call methods at runtime.